# how to setup MySQL and JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, 21.04

How to properly setup MySQL and JDBC properly in ubuntu 21.04.

Online Tutorials are not helpful at all

Comment: I could certainly answer this question, but my response would *technically* be an online tutorial, which you have not found useful at all. Could you update your question to include some of the things you’ve tried? This will make it easier to know *how* to help 

Comment: I will try your tutorial please send the link

Comment: I actually installed mysql but wasnt able to configure it properly for reasons i dont now                 Secondly i installed mardiadb-connector